# android layout AlignParent right its be match parent

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>





    <customfonts.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ssz"
        android:id="@+id/profile" />






    <customfonts.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circulo"
        android:text="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        />




      </RelativeLayout>
```

the result image

[image]

now the result good but when i try to make the text on right of image by use

```
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

on `textView`

result will be like this

[image]

how can i solve it and make the `textView` align on right image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to align it to the parent. The parent is the RelativeLayout. You want to align it to the image. This should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

    <customfonts.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ssz"/>

    <customfonts.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circulo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profile"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="13dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i don't see align left or right on code now how can i make it align left ?

Comment: It has `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profile"` just change that to `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile"`

Comment: You would need to remove it and re-add it with different layout params

Answer (score 2):

Currently the parent of text view is relative layout . if you want text view on the right side of image view,the parent of textview should be image view or another view that it's parent is relative layout. you must nest textview in the Imageview or you can nest imageview in another view and then nest texttview in that view.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>

    <customfonts.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ssz"
        android:id="@+id/profile" />
    <customfonts.MyTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circulo"
        android:text="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile"
        />

      </RelativeLayout>
```